# Changing the fontsize with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

The code below adds `<font size="x">$text</font>` to the WYSIWYG editor's textarea:

```
/**
* Set Size Context
*/
this.set_size_context = function(sizestate)
{
    if (this.buttons['fontsize'])
    {
        if (typeof sizestate == 'undefined')
        {
            sizestate = this.editdoc.queryCommandValue('fontsize');
        }
        switch (sizestate)
        {
            case null:
            case '':
            {
                if (is_moz)
                {
                    sizestate = this.translate_fontsize(this.editdoc.body.style.fontSize);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        if (sizestate != this.sizestate)
        {
            this.sizestate = sizestate;
            var i;

            if (this.popupmode)
            {
                for (i in this.sizeoptions)
                {
                    if (YAHOO.lang.hasOwnProperty(this.sizeoptions, i))
                    {
                        this.sizeoptions[i].style.display = (i == this.sizestate ? '' : 'none');
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (i = 0; i < this.buttons['fontsize'].options.length; i++)
                {
                    if (this.buttons['fontsize'].options[i].value == this.sizestate)
                    {
                        this.buttons['fontsize'].selectedIndex = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I replaced `<font size` tags with `<span style="font-size` tags in PHP side and everthing is working except the fontsize dropdown menu and the editor is still adding `<font size` when I choose a font size from the list. (it's correctly converted to `<span style="font-size` when the message is posted or previewed).

The question is, how the code above generates `<font size` tag and how can i replace it with `<span style="font-size` ?

Below are the other related sections to the fontsize in the JS:

```
this.build_fontsize_popup = function(obj, menu)
{
    for (var n in sizeoptions)
    {
        if (YAHOO.lang.hasOwnProperty(sizeoptions, n))
        {
            var option = document.createElement('div');
            option.innerHTML = '<span style="font-size:' + sizeoptions[n] + '">' + sizeoptions[n] + '</span>'; 
            option.className = 'osize';
            option.style.textAlign = 'center';
            option.title = sizeoptions[n];
            option.cmd = obj.cmd;
            option.controlkey = obj.id;
            option.editorid = this.editorid;
            option.onmouseover = option.onmouseout = option.onmouseup = option.onmousedown = vB_Text_Editor_Events.prototype.menuoption_onmouseevent;
            option.onclick = vB_Text_Editor_Events.prototype.formatting_option_onclick;
            menu.appendChild(option);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
this.translate_fontsize = function(csssize)
{
    switch (csssize)
    {
        case '15px':
        case '12px': return 1;
        case '15px': return 2;
        case '18px': return 3;
        case '21px': return 4;
        case '24px': return 5;
        case '27px': return 6;
        case '30px': return 7;
        default:     return '';
    }
}
```

Here is the complete JS file: https://jsfiddle.net/07ttt9a7/

Comment: Seems to miss the place where it does the actual `<font` or `string.fontsize(...)`

Comment: I added the complete JS file. Btw, the original line was:


`option.innerHTML='<font size="'+sizeoptions[n]+'">'+sizeoptions[n]+"</font>";`

Answer (score 1):

Wading though the full code, you need to fix the

```
case 'fontname':
            {
                this.wrap_tags('font', argument);
                return;
            }
```

to use 'span' instead of 'font'

or

modify the function beginning with

```
this.wrap_tags = function(tagname, useoption, selection)
{
```

Comment: That is for the "font face > font-family" replacement.

Font size has the lines below and it has "size" instead of font:

    `case 'fontname':
    {
     this.wrap_tags('font', argument);
     return;
    }

    case 'fontsize':
    {
     this.wrap_tags('size', argument);
     return;
    }` Thanks for your reply.

Comment: So this is what you needed ?

Comment: No, the editor adds `<font size="x"></font>`. I need to replace it with `<span style="font-size:xpx"></span>`, but i can't find where else i should change in the JS.

Comment: And if you change `this.wrap_tags('font', argument)` to `this.wrap_tags('span', argument)` and then `alert(opentag + selection + closetag;')` on line 1130? What do you see? `<span size="x">...</span>` ?

Comment: Hmmm - weird - I am not near a computer.

Comment: Before clickling the preview button:
http://i.imgur.com/YaANaME.png 

After: http://i.imgur.com/Cducr1a.png